Changing a set of ODE to SDE's
I'm trying to add noise to a system I have of ODE's which I solve using NDSolveValue
It is written as follows (I did not specify here the functions as they are lengthy, and I'd like to keep the question general)
{Asol, Usol}=NDSolveValue[{A'[t] == 
dAdt[A[t], u[t]], u'[t] == dudt[A[t], u[t]], A[0] == .5, u[0] == 10^-4}, {A, u}, {t, 0, 50}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

what I do now is add
noise[t_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]A]];

and change the above to
    {Asol, Usol}=NDSolveValue[{A'[t] == 
    dAdt[A[t], u[t]] + noise[t], u'[t] == dudt[A[t], u[t]], A[0] == .5, u[0] == 10^-4}, {A, u}, {t, 
   0, 50}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

i.e, I added the noise directly to A.
The problem is that the solutions look the same without adding the noise, how can one make the addition of the noise proper?

NDSolve and friends don't do SDE's. Have a look at the guide for SDEs if the functionality you need can be found there. In particular ItoProcess might be useful to you.

The reason it fails is that noise[t] is evaluated only once. You need something like ClearAll[noise]; noise[t_?NumericQ] := ... for it to be evaluated repeatedly. But as @Sjoerd said, NDSolve[] still won't like it, probably. :) The error estimators used by NDSolve[] are intended for smooth functions, with NDSolve handling isolated weak singularities.
You could try it with the "FixedStep" method I suppose, since it turns off error estimation.
ClearAll[noise];
noise[t_?NumericQ] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5]];
sol = NDSolveValue[{A'[t] == -u[t] + noise[t] A[t], 
   u'[t] == A[t] + noise[t] u[t], A[0] == .5, u[0] == 10^-4}, {A, 
   u}, {t, 0, 50}, 
  Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}]


ParametricPlot[Through[sol[t]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 50}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &)]


SDEs are outside my area of expertise. For instance, what happens when the ODE is reevaluated at the same t? You get a new value in the above code and probably not the same one. That sounds bad. I cannot be totally sure what goes on under the hood in NDSolve[].
By comparison, here is a similar Ito process:
proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]A[
       t] == -u[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w1[
        t], \[DifferentialD]u[t] == 
     A[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w2[t]},
   {A[t], u[t]}, {{A, u}, {0.5, 10^-4}}, t,
   {w1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 0.5], 
    w2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 0.5]}];

td = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 50., 0.01}];

Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[2],
  With[{pts = First@td["ValueList"]},
   Line[pts, 
    VertexColors -> ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale@N@Range@Length@pts]
   ]},
 Axes -> True]



Probably should have used a smaller volatility on the WienerProcess to get a more similar plot.

The method suggested above does not work with equations which require a solving method of "EquationSimplification->"Residual".

@jarhead Nope, only the IDA method is available for "EquationSimplification->"Residual", and it requires continuous equations. I'm not even sure what it means to solve an implicit equation (the "residual") when there is random noise every time you evaluate it. You could try memoizing noise[].  It seems to run, but you're still using a method that assumes the functions are continuous. NDSolve[] will take steps small enough to cancel out the noise ($\Delta t \approx 5\times10^{-8}$, probably depending on PrecisionGoal). ItoProcess is the way to go, but you need an explicit equation

The OP did not supply an MWE to work wth, even after being dissatisfied with my first answer, but wanted one that uses "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual". Mainly because I was curious if I understood NDSolve[] well enough to make something work that probably shouldn't, I offer another possibility, which is an implicit DE taken modified from the examples for NDSolve (Scope > Differential-Algebraic Equations, second example):
m = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 100}, {1, 1, 100}};
s = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
f // ClearAll;
f[t_?NumericQ] = {Sin[t], Cos[t], 3};

noise // ClearAll;
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == \[DifferentialD]w[t], 
   x[t], {x, 0}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1/100]];
step = 1/8;
noise[t_?NumericQ] = 
  D[Through[Interpolation[RandomFunction[proc, {0, 50, step}, 3]][t]],
    t];

rn = NDSolve[{m . X'[t] == s . X[t] + f[t] + noise[t], 
    X[0] == {0.8, 0.6, 1.},
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, step] == 0, "RestartIntegration"]}, {X}, {t, 0, 
    50}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"},
   PrecisionGoal -> -16, (* Yikes! *)
   MaxStepSize -> step]; (* This controls precision of solution *)

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[X[t] /. rn], {t, 0, 50}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]


Here's the original NDSolve[] example (without noise):
r = NDSolve[{m . X'[t] == s . X[t] + f[t], X[0] == {0.8, 0.6, 1.}(*,
    X'[0]\[Equal]{0.6,1.4,0.01}*)(*,
    WhenEvent[Mod[t,step]==0,"RestartIntegration"]*)}, {X}, {t, 0, 
    50}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[X[t] /. r], {t, 0, 50}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]


